Strange behavior with dictionary using constants
I am defining two dictionaries using two different methods and they behave in different way. Can someone explain why?
const PORTRAIT = 'PRT';
const LANDSCAPE = 'LND';
const SQUARE = 'SQ';

const good_image_ratios = {}
good_image_ratios[LANDSCAPE] = '16_9_';
good_image_ratios[PORTRAIT] = '3_4_';
good_image_ratios[SQUARE] = '1_1_';

const wrong_image_ratios = { LANDSCAPE: '16_9_', PORTRAIT: '3_4_', SQUARE : '1_1_'  }

console.log(good_image_ratios);
console.log(wrong_image_ratios);

console.log(good_image_ratios[LANDSCAPE]);
console.log(wrong_image_ratios[LANDSCAPE]);

The output is as follow:
{ LND: '16_9_', PRT: '3_4_', SQ: '1_1_' }
{ LANDSCAPE: '16_9_', PORTRAIT: '3_4_', SQUARE: '1_1_' }
16_9_
undefined

Why is this?

{ LANDSCAPE: '16_9_', - the interpreter simply has no way of knowing that you tried to refer to a constant here - because object keys don't need quotes in that notation, if they don't contain any special characters. To the interpreter, LANDSCAPE is a valid key here, so it can be taken literally.

You need to put the LANDSCAPE etc in square brackets for the second syntax. See JavaScript set object key by variable.

Use dynamic object property syntax with square brackets, otherwise the property names are interpreted as strings, not variable names:


const PORTRAIT = 'PRT';
const LANDSCAPE = 'LND';
const SQUARE = 'SQ';

const good_image_ratios = {}
good_image_ratios[LANDSCAPE] = '16_9_';
good_image_ratios[PORTRAIT] = '3_4_';
good_image_ratios[SQUARE] = '1_1_';

const wrong_image_ratios = { [LANDSCAPE]: '16_9_', [PORTRAIT]: '3_4_', [SQUARE] : '1_1_'  }

console.log(good_image_ratios);
console.log(wrong_image_ratios);

console.log(good_image_ratios[LANDSCAPE]);
console.log(wrong_image_ratios[LANDSCAPE]);



